# Powershell Neo4j connectivity Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, security, neo4j, passwords, unauthorized

I am trying to connect to a Neo4j via Invoke-RestMethod (PowerShell versions 3,4,5).

Based on web recommendations, I am setting URI:
$Uri        = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher"

... followed by a call to invoke rest method (POST or GET, does not matter)

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Body $Body -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Message I get is:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
```

I tried putting in http://userId/pwd@localhost:7474....
but the error is the same.

Is there another way to pass authentication information to Neo4j?

Disabling security is not an option.

Thank you!

--Alex

Answer (score 0):

The authetication havs to bee the http standard authentication. You can do this in powershell for example with the following code.

```
    $user = 'user'
$pass = 'pass'

$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"

$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))

$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

$Headers = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Body $Body -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $Headers
```

**Background**
The error code 401 says that the authentication is not correct on the server.

I found this information in the documentation.
https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/http-api/authentication/

Comment: this is the path I took as well, and it comes back with an error:

errors
------
{@{code=Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat; message=U

Comment: That signals that the authetifcation succeeds but the request has not all information that needed. "The client provided a request that was missing required fields, or had values that are not allowed." See documentation https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/reference/status-codes/